# Can I use Prisma as the ORM inside of Django instead of Django's ORM?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, prisma

I'd like to use Django + Django Rest Framework as my backend for a bunch of reasons (maturity, great tooling, security, etc.). I'm curious about using Prisma as the ORM layer instead of Django's ORM. Is there anything technically infeasible with this setup, or are there any major gotchas that may not be obvious that would make this a terrible idea?

Comment: Django's models do far more than an ORM, it also is used to generate forms, migrations, etc. So possible, yes. But it will nullify most of how Django can help.

Comment: @WillemVOsupportsmodstrike good points. I will use the backend only for DRF to power a separate single page app hosted on Netlify or Vercel or the like, so I'm not concerned with template generation. Prisma can do migrations also.

Comment: Did you had a look at Prisma Python Client?
https://prisma-client-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Comment: One is python and one is typescript, so no.  What exactly are you trying to do here?

Comment: @NurulSundarani yes, that was what I was thinking of using instead of Django's ORM

Comment: @Andrew Prisma has a Python client

Comment: @kevlar Yes, it has a _client_, as mentioned previously in the comments.  If you wan to replace django's orm with this you will need a lot more: everything you will use will expect a propery queryset.  If you want just introspect the database and generate unmanaged tables in django/drf that will work fine, but is a pain.  If you don't, then you can't really use any of the standard methods unless you can customize their generated code... It _can_ work (see django+mongo) but it's not super fun.

Comment: Prisma Python Client is pretty stable if you want to give it a try.

Comment: @AndrewYou raise a good point that some things in Django or DRF require a queryset. Perhaps for that reason, it's not convenient to use other ORM objects. One example that comes to mind are DRF serializers. I mainly intend to use DRF though and none of Django's view templating (this is purely an API backend), so it may not be too much of a constraint.